# How to import svn ressources to microsoft word?

Tags: vba, svn, ms-word, export-to-word

I must create some documentation with mircosoft word.

Well, I have several resources within my sofware project which I need to show in my documentation. Now I would like to invoke some kind of `svn export myserver.com/someFile` to insert files into my word document.

The files I am talking about are png, pdf, and text-files.

How to import svn ressources to microsoft word?

Comment: I'm not really sure, what problem you are facing. The files that are in the repository are still files. If you have a checkout of them (or an export) you can add them to your word file like every other file ..

Comment: I must not check out the resources. I must use the resources as external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Here is a step by step instruction.

1. Select 'Einfügen' --> 'Schnellbausteine' --> 'Feld'

[image: paste]

2. Select 'IncludePicture' and type in your web address

[image: dialog]

3. To update all external references just press ctrl+a and then F9.

PS: Shame on me, I must use Microsoft Word with German language. If someone can provide English screen shots and and English captions I would be very thankfully.

Comment: What do you input as filename or url? svn://...?

Comment: I am using my http access to my svn repository. So I use something like http://...